# Generic Classes

Tags: java, generics, scjp

Place code into the class so that it compiles & generates the out put
answer=42

Note:Code options may be used more than once.

[image]

This question is from SCJP , I have posted answer. I can't understand why they used

```
public Gen (T object){this.object = object}
```

instread of

```
public T ( T object){this.object = object}
```

i am getting confused in this. Please help me out

Comment: Why should have they used `T(T object)`? That's a constructor. And name of the class is `Gen`.

Comment: because constructor name should be equal to class name

Comment: Well, this is supposed to return a `Gen` object that takes a parameter of type `T`. To get the object, call `T getObject()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`public Gen (T object){this.object = object}` is the constructor.

The constructor MUST have the exact same name as the class

Answer (score 0):

Because gen is the class name here, where T is the generic. So Its class Gen with object type T. If you said class T then T would be the class name and not the object type.

Answer (score 0):

Because `public Gen (T object){this.object = object}` is the constructor of the class `Gen`

Answer (score 0):

In the `constructor signature`, the `constructor name`, must match the `class name`. Also, why T would represent `Gen type`?. The whole idea is getting compile type safety when using statements like `Gen<String>, Gen<Integer>...`